# Finding the where clause in a query string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that has a query.

The problem is I cannot just append to it, after the where clause there is a group by.

So say i'm given this string:

```
var query = "select stuff from db where something = 3 group by stuff"
```

Now I want to append `"somethingelse > 5 AND "`

Result:

```
query = "select stuff from db where somethingelse > 5 AND something = 3 group by stuff"
```

What do I need to do to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
query = query.replace(/where/,'where somethingelse > 5 AND');
```

Answer (score 0):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952024/45664) is the most pragmatic if you are passed the query string as-is.

Alternatively, if you're building it up yourself it may be better to allow the list of selectors, query constraints etc. to be passed in so that you create a correct query string initially.  Something a bit like:

```
val query = "select " + selectors.join() +
            " from " + tables.join() +
            " where " + constraints.join() +
            " group by " + groupings.join()
```